# Java byecode maniulation to detect potential deadlocks

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I've been caught by yet another deadlock in our Java application and started thinking about how to detect potential deadlocks in the future. I had an idea of how to do this, but it seems almost too simple.

I'd like to hear people's views on it.

I plan to run our application for several hours in our test environment, using a typical data set.

I think it would be possible to perform bytecode manipulation on our application such that, whenever it takes a lock (e.g. entering a synchronized block), details of the lock are added to a ThreadLocal list.

I could write an algorithm that, at some later point, compares the lists for all threads and checks if any contain the same pair of locks in opposite order - this would be reported as a deadlock possibility. Again, I would use bytecode manipulation to add this periodic check to my application.

So my question is this: is this idea (a) original and (b) viable?

Comment: Mmmmm, you might be better off using something like Guava's [`CycleDetectingLockFactory`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/CycleDetectingLockFactory.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that we talked about when I took a course in concurrency. I'm not sure if your implementation is original, but the concept of analysis to determine potential deadlock is not unique. There are dynamic analysis tools for Java, such as [JCarder](http://www.jcarder.org/). There is also research into [some analysis that can be done statically](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1488042).

Admittedly, it's been a couple of years since I've looked around. I don't think JCarder was the specific tool we talked about (at least, the name doesn't sound familiar, but I couldn't find anything else). But the point is that analysis to detect deadlock isn't an original concept, and I'd start by looking at research that has produced usable tools as a starting point - I would suspect that the algorithms, if not the implementation, are generally available.

Answer (score 3):

I have done something similar to this with `Lock` by supplying my own implementation.

These days I use the [actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model), so there is little need to lock the data (as I have almost no shared mutable data)

Comment: shared => immutable, mutable => local to one thread e.g. single thread ExecutorService.

Comment: This should leave you with very little or no *shared and mutable* data which requires locking.

Answer (score 2):

In case you didn't know, you can use the [Java MX bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#findMonitorDeadlockedThreads%28%29) to detect deadlocked threads programmatically.  This doesn't help you in testing but it will help you at least better detect and recover in production.

```
ThreadMXBean threadMxBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
long[] deadLockedThreadIds = threadMxBean.findMonitorDeadlockedThreads();
// log the condition or even interrupt threads if necessary
...
```

Comment: I thought of that too, but he is looking for potential deadlocks which have not turning into actual deadlocks in testing.

Answer (score 0):

That way you can find some deadlocks, but never prove their absence. I'd better develop static checking tool, a kind of bytecode analizer, feeded with annotations for each synchronized method. Annotations should show the place of the annotated method in the resource graph. The task is then to find loops in the graph. Each loop means deadlock.